# String tokenizer for PHP

Tags: php

I have used the String Tokenizer in Java. I wish to know if there is similar functionality for PHP. I have a string and I want to extract individual words from it.

eg. If the string is -

```
Summer is doubtful #haiku #poetry #babel
```

I want to know if it contains the hashtag `#haiku`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strpos`](https://www.php.net/strpos), [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/stripos), [`strstr`](https://www.php.net/strstr), [`stristr`](https://www.php.net/strstr) are easy solutions.

`strpos` example:

```
$haikuIndex = strpos( $str, '#haiku' ); 
if( $haikuIndex !== FALSE ) {
   // "#haiku" exists
}
```

`strstr` example:

```
$haikuExists = strstr( $str, '#haiku' );

if( $haikuExists !== FALSE ) {
   // "#haiku" exists
}
```

Comment: Aah, I see you have fallen into the old pit. Always compare the result of `strpos` to `=== false`! It's even written in the manual entry you linked to.

Comment: Yeah, it slipped my mind. I've been doing too much Objective-C lately to remember just how loosely typed (read:unpredictable) PHP is.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a string **tokenizer**, then you probably want the [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) function

```
<?php
$string = "Summer is doubtful #haiku #poetry #babel";
$tok = strtok($string, " ");
while ($tok !== false) {
    if ($tok == "#haiku") {
        // #haiku exists
    }
    $tok = strtok(" ");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
if (strlen(strstr($str,'#haiku')) > 0) // "#haiku" exists
```

Comment: From the manual of `strstr`: If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.